# How to read two files into a dict and print specific values

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, dictionary

So, I am learning python and have these fun assignments

I have two files `rating_strikers1.txt` and `rating_strikers2.txt` where they have rated some football strikers from 1 to 99.

The textfile `rating_strikers1` has this in it:

```
Kane ; 85

Aubameyang ; 80

Werner ; 76

Lukaku ; 88
```

The textfile "rating_strikers2" has this in it:

```
Kane ; 85

Aubameyang ; 80

Werner ; 76

Lukaku ; 88

Lacazette ; 75

Antonio ; 80
```

I have to read these files into a `dict` and check if a `key` is also in the other file. However, I also need to only print out ratings that are 80 or more.

I want to define a function that reads the file and returns a `dict`.

expected output: print out all the strikers that 'rating_strikers1.txt' and 'rating_strikers2.txt' both rated with 80 or more.

Comment: you should use `csv` module with `dictreader` as reader and it will make your work easier, and if you are freshly learning python so learn python 3.10 not 2.7 as 2.7 got end of life.

Comment: Do you try anything on this problem?  - 1) read the file by `open`, and `read` `readline` ... 2) parsing each line by `spliting`, 3) put into dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
def myfunc():
     files = list()
     files.append(open('rating_strikers1.txt', 'r'))
     files.append(open('rating_strikers2.txt', 'r'))
     outdict = dict()

     for file in files:
          for line in file.read().splitlines():
               try:
                    key, value = line.split(" ; ")
                    if key not in outdict.keys():
                         outdict[key] = list()
                    outdict[key].append(int(value))
               except:
                    pass

     
     for key, value in outdict.items():
          if all(x >= 80 for x in value):
               print(key, value)

myfunc()
```

Comment: output in this func is working. However, lets say Werner is rated 80 on the other list, he would appear in the output because he is now 80 on one list, but lower in the other. The output would show the following  >>>  Werner 76 80

Comment: @course.py please edit your question and explain your expected output.

Comment: print out all the strikers that 'rating_strikers1.txt' and 'rating_strikers2.txt' both rated with 80 or more.

Comment: @course.py check it now.

Comment: This error appears: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @course.py it only needs a simple `cast`.

Comment: even with a cast of int() or str() same error appears

Comment: @course.py I already edited the code and there is no error in that.

Comment: @course.py your welcome. If it works for you please mark it as accepted answer.